# I am trying to understand code coverage in Salesforce

Tags: code-coverage, code

I have read several blogs, but wanted to clarify few things.

Is code coverage calculated for each class or over for the entire
org? 
Does it include the code coverage of managed packaged? 
During deployment, does it check code coverage of only the deployed classes or entire org? 
Does is code coverage related to the test parametes?
Can we pass any parameters to ignore the code coverage failures?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/11/how-code-coverage-works.html and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_code_coverage_best_pract.htm

Comment: Some more info of how code coverage is calculated. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_code_coverage_intro.htm . It is on Org level and not individual classes/triggers level

Answer (score 1):

1. Is code coverage calculated for each class or over for the entire org

   Yes (And triggers)
2. Does it include the code coverage of managed packaged

No

3. During deployment, does it check code coverage of only the deployed classes or entire org

   ```
    NO, entire org
   ```
4. Does is code coverage related to the test parametes

   ```
    Not sure I understand
   ```
5. Can we pass any parameters to ignore the code coverage failures

   ```
    No
   ```